# WPF command parameter how to use

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to have two kind of status**(SmallPay,Credit)**, but that is decided by previous `UserControl(ItemDetail.xaml)`

**ItemDetail.xaml**

```
<Border Background="#fb5106" CornerRadius="8" Cursor="Hand">
    <Border.InputBindings>
       <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Path=ClickPhoneNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="A"/>
    </Border.InputBindings>
    <TextBlock Text="SmallPay" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="32" />
</Border>

<Border Grid.Column="2" Background="#e7001f" CornerRadius="8" Cursor="Hand">
    <Border.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding Path=ClickPhoneNumberCommand}" CommandParameter="B"/>
        </Border.InputBindings>
    <TextBlock Text="Credit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="32" />
</Border>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public DelegateCommand ClickItemCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
        {
            SelectedPopupType = PopupTypes.ItemDetail;
                IsShowPopup = true;
        });
    }
}

public DelegateCommand ClickPhoneNumberCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(delegate ()
        {
            SelectedPopupType = PopupTypes.PhoneNumber;
            IsShowPopup = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Then I want to get the `commandParameter` in the `UserControl` opened by '`ClickPhoneNumberCommand`'.
But, I dont know how? Is there way without no `ViewModel`?

Comment: Are you using a ViewModel not? It's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: I'm using ViewModel.cs as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code returns a **new** delegate for each return of the `ClickItemCommand` property. I don't think this will work with WPF because of how object-references work, I think you should use a field to store a single reference to an immutable `Command`, like so:

```
private readonly DelegateCommand clickItemCommand;

public MyViewModel()
{
    this.clickItemCommand = new DelegateCommand( this.OnItemClick );
}

private void OnItemClick(Object parameter)
{
    this.SelectedPopupType = PopupTypes.ItemDetail;
    this.IsShowPopup = true;
}

public DelegateCommand ClickItemCommand
{
    get { retrn this.clickItemCommand; }
}
```